# x:Bind and UserControls

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use compiled **bindings** in UWP with a simple use case.

In order to make my XAML more readable easy to manage, I've extracted the XAML of a DataTemplate to a UserControl. So I transformed this

## MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ProjectItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

Into this

## MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ProjectItem">
                <local:MyUserControl1 />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

## MyUserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that it doesn't even compile because `x:Bind` doesn't know the context.

How does x:Bind cover this use case?

Comment: Using `x:Bind` binds to the Framework element (code-behind class) and it needs to have all types fixed at compile time. Why even use `x:Bind` in this case?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Why? Compile-time safety for example.

Comment: @mm8 good point as the user is already seeing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this approach, you could (or rather need to) add a property to `MyUserControl1.xaml.cs` that casts the current `DataContext` to a `ProjectItem` and returns it:

```
public ProjectItem Item => DataContext as ProjectItem;

public MyUserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += (s, e) => Bindings.Update();
}
```

You then bind to this property in the XAML markup:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Item.Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Item.Description}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The other option would to use non-compiled `{Bindings}` or get rid of `MyUserControl1` and revert to the inline `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest create Dependency Property for ProjectItem on your MyUserControl1.xaml.cs

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ProjectItem),
            typeof(ProjectItem),
            typeof(MyUserControl1),
            null);

    public ProjectItem ProjectItem
    {
        get => (ProjectItem)GetValue(ProjectItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProjectItemProperty, value);
    }
```

Then on your XAML, bind the properties of your ProjectItem Dependency Property:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ProjectItem.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ProjectItem.Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then on your MainPage.xaml, pass on the 'ProjectItem' collection item.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ProjectItem">
            <local:MyUserControl1 ProjectItem="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What if `ProjectItem` has 10 Properties? then you need to create 10 Dependancy properties. So instead we can try and create one Dependancy Property as `ProjectItem`? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This could be faster as the `DataContext` is casted only once when the `Control` is `Loaded`.

```
public ProjectItem ProjectItem { get; private set; }

public MyUserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, e) => 
    {
        ProjectItem = (ProjectItem)DataContext;
        Bindings.Update();
    };
}
```

Add this if `DataContext` change in `MainPage`:

```
    DataContextChanged += (s, e) => 
    {
        ProjectItem = (ProjectItem)DataContext;
        Bindings.Update();
    };
```

Based on the answer given by [@mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8).